# How to setup pytest for Sanic & Tortoise with test database?

Tags: python, pytest, sanic, tortoise-orm, pytest-asyncio

I am trying to use [sanic-testing](https://github.com/sanic-org/sanic-testing) but i can't find example and how no idea how to setup this with test database (e.g. sqlite in memory).

I was tried create test database and connect tortoise to it on other fixtures and add to the app listeners which connect to test db and clean/drop it after test but im always have errors with fixtures, event loop and tortoise connection to the database.

Can you please show me example of pytest setup for sanic application which will use tortoise orm and test database (sqlite:///:memory fits in my case) for testing CRUD application?

Thank you!